# An error in a line after the code?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to build a function for fitting of my data. I'm using CurveExpert and the lines are in python. I'm no expert so after trying, it says I have an error one line after the end of the return (last line). Can you please help me? I want to note that I tried to copy an existing format of another function.
Thanks in advance!

```
    name          = ur"Diffusion"
    nindvar       = 1
    equation      = r"8.4*erfc(a/(2*sqrt(13.6094*x*b)))"
    latexequation = r"8.4\mathrm{erfc}{\left(a/{left(2\sqrt{13.6094 x b\right)}\right)}"

    def evaluate(x,a,b):
      """
      """
      y = 8.4*erfc(a/(2*sqrt(13.6094*x*b)))
     return y

     def initialize(x,y):
      """
      """
     try:
       a = 74
       b = 0.37
     return a,b
```

Comment: Check out the indentation

Comment: Your indentation is all messed up, please fix it. Indentation matters in Python, and it's crucial for us to understand your problem, and might actually be the reason for the error you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have try without except.